# Change order status after successful FTP export

Tags: magento-1.8, order-status, csv, export

I am using a Cron job to export orders to a third party warehouse system every two hours via FTP which has been working fine.

The problem is I need to change the order status once the FTP upload has completed to prevent duplicate orders being sent across.

Currently the Cron runs every two hours and checks for orders with status "ready to ship" then adds the orders to a CSV file and uploads it to FTP but for some reason the order status doesn't change so when the Cron runs again it resends the same orders to FTP causing duplicates.

We also PayPal IPN so all new orders get set to "ready to ship" when the funds have been captured.

Here's my Cron.php file

```
      private static function exportOrdersToCSV()
        {
            Mage::log('exportOrdersToCSV');

            // Make CSV filename
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS . 'orders' . DS;

            $date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
            $filename = $path. $date->format('Y-m-d-H'). '_ilg_feed.csv';
            //$filename = $path. date('Y-m-d-H'). '_ilg_feed.csv';

            // Select orders to export
            $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'ready_to_ship');

            $order_str = 'DATE,ORDER REF,CONTACT NAME,COMPANY,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,TOWN,COUNTY,POSTCODE,COUNTRY,COUNTRY CODE,PRODUCT CODE,QTY,CUSTOMER REFERENCE,TELEPHONE,MOBILENO,COMMENTS,EMAIL,SHIPPERS REF,DELIVERY TYPE,ORDER ORIGIN,CUSTOMS VALUE,DELIVERY INSTRUCTIONS,OPTION1,OPTION2,OPTION3,OPTION4,OPTION5,OPTION6,OPTION7,OPTION8,OPTION9,OPTION10'. "\n";
            $orders_ary = array();
            foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $orders_ary[] = $order->getEntityId();
                $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();

                $date = explode(' ', $order->getCreatedAtFormated('short'));
                $order_info1 = array(
                    $date[0],
                    $order->getEntityId(),
                    $shippingAddress->getName(),
                    $shippingAddress->getCompany(),
                    $shippingAddress->getStreet(1),
                    $shippingAddress->getStreet(2),
                    $shippingAddress->getStreet(3),
                    $shippingAddress->getCity(),
                    $shippingAddress->getRegion(),
                    $shippingAddress->getPostcode(),
                    $shippingAddress->getCountry(),
                    $shippingAddress->getCountryId()
                );

                // Set delivery type
                $delivery_type = $order->getShippingMethod() === 'flatrate_flatrate' ? 'ND' : 'RMT'; // next day or Royal Mail
                $order_info2 = array(
                    $order->getCustomerId(),
                    (strlen($shippingAddress->getTelephone()) > 1) ? $shippingAddress->getTelephone() : $order->getPhone(),
                    '', // mobile
                    '', // comments
                    $shippingAddress->getEmail(),
                    '', // shippers ref
                    $delivery_type, // delivery type
                    'WEB',  // order origin
                );
                $order_info3 = array(
                    '', // delivery instructions
                    '','','','','','','','','',''   // OPTION1-OPTION10
                );

                $items = $order->getItemsCollection(array(), true);
                foreach ($items AS $item) {
                    //Mage::log('Adding product #'. $item->getSku(). ' to order '. $order->getEntityId());
                    $product = array(
                        $item->getSku(),
                        intval($item->getQtyOrdered())
                    );
                    $customs_value = array('');

                    $ary = array_merge($order_info1, $product, $order_info2, $customs_value, $order_info3);
                    $order_str .= '"'. implode('","', $ary). '"'. "\n";
                }
            }

            if (count($orders_ary) === 0) {
                return null;
            }

            // Save to file
            $ret = array();
            if (file_put_contents($filename, $order_str) !== false) {
                $ret['orders'] = array_unique($orders_ary);
                $ret['filename'] = $filename;
            }

            return $ret;
        } 

 /**
     * FTP orders CSV file to 3PL FTP server
     */
    private static function ftpOrdersTo3PL($orders_ary)
    {
        Mage::log('ftpOrdersTo3PL');
        $filename = $orders_ary['filename'];

        if (!$filename) {
            throw new \Exception('FTP CSV filename not specified');
        }

        if (!file_exists($filename)) {
            throw new \Exception('FTP CSV file '. $filename. ' not found');
        }        

        $ftp_server = self::FTP_SERVER;
        $ftp_user = self::FTP_USER;
        $ftp_password = self::FTP_PASSWORD;

        //if (!($ftp = ftp_ssl_connect($ftp_server))) {
        if (!($ftp = ftp_connect($ftp_server))) {
            throw new \Exception('FTP connection to '. $ftp_server. ' failed');
        }

        if (!ftp_login($ftp, $ftp_user, $ftp_password)) {
            ftp_close($ftp);
            throw new \Exception('FTP login as '. $ftp_user. ' failed');
        }

        if (!ftp_pasv($ftp, true)) {
            ftp_close($ftp);
            throw new \Exception('FTP failed to switch to passive mode');
        }

        $remote_filename = self::FTP_CSV_DIR. DS. basename($filename);
        if (!ftp_put($ftp, $remote_filename, $filename, FTP_BINARY)) {
            ftp_close($ftp);
            throw new \Exception('FTP failed to put '. $filename. ' to '. $remote_filename);
        }

        ftp_close($ftp);

        // If the file upload succeeds then change the status of the orders to indicate they went to the 3PL
        if (is_array($orders_ary['orders'])) {
            $auth_token = self::getBrightpearlAuthToken();        


            foreach ($orders_ary['orders'] as $orderid) {
                Mage::log('Updating order #'. $orderid. ' status to packing');
                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
                $incrementid = $order->getIncrementId();
                $order->setState('processing', 'packing', 'Order sent to 3PL for packing', false)->save();

                // Update the order status in Brightpearl
                if (($bp_orderid = self::getBrightpearlOrderId($auth_token, $incrementid)) !== null) {
                    Mage::log('Updating status for BP order '. $bp_orderid. ' ('. $incrementid. ')');
                    self::setBrightpearlOrderStatus($auth_token, $bp_orderid);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line where order status should change isn't firing and I can't figure out what the problem is and could do with some help here please...!

[image]

exception.log

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `index_p...', Array)
#4 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `index_p...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `index_p...', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Process.php(137): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('index_process', Array, Array)
#7 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Process.php(150): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process->_updateProcessData('8', Array)
#8 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(277): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Process->updateProcessStartDate(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Process))
#9 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(638): Mage_Index_Model_Process->processEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#10 [internal function]: Mage_Index_Model_Process->safeProcessEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#11 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(366): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#12 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(246): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->_runAll('safeProcessEven...', Array)
#13 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(317): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->indexEvent(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#14 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php(792): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->processEntityAction(Object(Plumrocket_Cartreservation_Model_Override_CatalogInventory_Stock_Item), 'cataloginventor...', 'save')
#15 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item->_afterSave()
#16 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(154): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#17 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->saveInventoryData(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'saveInventoryDa...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#19 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#20 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product...', Array)
#21 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(549): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#22 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterSave()
#23 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php(194): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#24 [internal function]: Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2->update('1412', Object(stdClass), NULL, NULL)
#25 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(296): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#26 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Handler.php(57): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->call('ae111f981dbfadd...', 'product.update', Array)
#27 [internal function]: Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler->__call('catalogProductU...', Array)
#28 [internal function]: Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler->catalogProductUpdate('ae111f981dbfadd...', '1412', Object(stdClass), NULL, NULL)
#29 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php(832): SoapServer->handle('<?xml version="...')
#30 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php(70): Zend_Soap_Server->handle()
#31 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php(138): Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Adapter_Soap->run()
#32 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/controllers/V2/SoapController.php(46): Mage_Api_Model_Server->run()
#33 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Api_V2_SoapController->indexAction()
#34 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#35 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#36 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#37 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#38 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#39 {main}
2014-06-05T07:31:18+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' in /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `index_e...', Array)
#5 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `index_e...', Array)
#6 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `index_e...', Array)
#7 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(433): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('index_event', Array, 'event_id='5776'')
#8 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Index_Model_Event))
#9 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(333): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php(792): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer->processEntityAction(Object(Plumrocket_Cartreservation_Model_Override_CatalogInventory_Stock_Item), 'cataloginventor...', 'save')
#11 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item->_afterSave()
#12 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item/Api/V2.php(61): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#13 [internal function]: Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item_Api_V2->update('2430', Object(stdClass))
#14 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Handler/Abstract.php(296): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Handler.php(57): Mage_Api_Model_Server_Handler_Abstract->call('fa4880704a9bbc9...', 'product_stock.u...', Array)
#16 [internal function]: Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler->__call('catalogInventor...', Array)
#17 [internal function]: Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Handler->catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate('fa4880704a9bbc9...', '2430', Object(stdClass))
#18 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php(832): SoapServer->handle('<?xml version="...')
#19 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/V2/Adapter/Soap.php(70): Zend_Soap_Server->handle()
#20 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server.php(138): Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_Adapter_Soap->run()
#21 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Api/controllers/V2/SoapController.php(46): Mage_Api_Model_Server->run()
#22 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Api_V2_SoapController->indexAction()
#23 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#24 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /chroot/home/home/testwebsite.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

Comment: Have you created the state 'packing' in the custom order statuses?

Comment: @B00MER Hi, yes we have 'packing' as an order status see screenshot...

Comment: If you have logging enabled, are there any exceptions or such in var/log `exceptions.log` or `system.log` ?

Comment: @B00MER the exception.log does show some deadlocks, could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Are any order statuses being set at all? If not then the deadlock is most likely not related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309341/magento-deadlocks

Comment: @B00MER Currently the only order being set is "Ready to ship" then we have to manually change the status to avoid the cron duplicating the order exports...

Comment: Sorry, I mean have you gotten any order to set to the `packing` state via the script at all? Or are just some failing and some are not?

Comment: @B00MER No, they simply stay as "ready to ship" even though they have been exported...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14922/discussion-between-b00mer-and-user1704524).

Comment: Can you add logging to your ftpOrdersTo3PL function to see how far through it gets? Ensure that $orders_ary['orders'] exists as an array. You don't mention if Mage::log('Updating order #'. $orderid. ' status to packing'); is getting hit?

Comment: @DouglasRadburn the Mage::log doesn't appear to be even getting hit...

Comment: Cool, so you know that it's not that part of the script :) Start adding more logging and find out how far it gets!